# Why XmlNode.SelectNodes returns empty list when XPath validator returns correct result?

Tags: python, .net, xpath, ironpython, xmlnode

The code is in IronPython and here it is:

```
for systemNode in csResultXML.SelectNodes("Response/SubSystems/SubSystem"):

    itemNodes = systemNode.SelectNodes('/SubSystem/Items/Item')
```

The value of systemNode in the single loop cycle is:

```
<SubSystem ID="0">
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>0.0</TotalPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>0.0</TotalPrice>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</SubSystem>
```

itemNodes is an empty list when the code finished.

Why?
XPath online validator returs results correctly.

Thank you for the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `systemNode.SelectNodes('Items/Item')` as you want to select the `Items` child element of the context node (your `systemNode` variable) and not the `Items` child element of the document node `/`.

Comment: Martin, apologies. I was using systemNode.SelectNodes('/SubSystem/Items/Item') , I have copy/pasted one of playing options at the top. I am editing the question.
But you are right, this did solve the problem.
I cannot tell why systemNode.SelectNodes('/SubSystem/Items/Item')  is not working.

Comment: Your first expression selects `SubSystem` elements and then to select elements inside you need to use a relative path like `Items/Item` and not an absolute path starting with `/`. And of course if the context node is already a `SubSystem` element you can't start with `SubSystem` again, unless you had nested `SubSystem` elements.